# Recode or case_when issue in combining variables using or

Tags: if-statement, case, recode

I am trying to use recode or case_when to create a subset of my dataset that includes variables that indicate a risk factor for HIV. Essentially, I have four variables that indicate HIV risk and I want to combine them so that I can say if this factor is present OR this factor is present OR this factor (to include the 4 factors).

Then I want to combine those to eliminate the people in my data set who do not have at least 1 of the 4 risk factors.

Can anyone help with the coding needed to do this?

Thanks so much, this is my first time typing a question on this site.

I have tried various versions of recode and case_when and ifelse all of which have not worked. I used similar code to determine who is HIV negative in my data set but that was based on Yes or No, and the risk factors follow an OR logic. Meaning I want to include all of the people who have at least 1 of the risk factors.